# Unity ParticleSystem.Simulate API under world space work wrong

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

the Particle System is set to simulated in world space, and i manually call simulate function from script, but it works still like in local space , that means the particles are like moving with emitter. i guess the simulate API don't memory the position of emitter ,so it will always simulate from current position , so it still works like local space. has anyone known a solution to make it still work like in world space when manually simulating?

```
void Update()
{
    ParticleSystem ps = this.particle.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

    ParticleSystem.MainModule mainModule = ps[j].main;
    mainModule.simulationSpace = ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.World;

    ps.Stop(false, ParticleSystemStopBehavior.StopEmittingAndClear);
    ps.Play(false);
    ps.Simulate(playbackTime, false, false, true);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you call `Stop` and `Play` every frame? I think the problem is you calling `ParticleSystemStopBehavior.StopEmittingAndClear`, then you simulate the state of a given time .. so yes it recalculates every frame from scratch and won't remember the last frames emissions .. why not using the particle system as it is intended?

Comment: @derHugo I know that it is intended but is there any solution that remember last frames emissions? I want to simulate animation and the particles about it in every frame.

Comment: @derHugo and I've confirmed that this is not a `Stop` and `Play` issue.
`ParticleSystem.Simulate` itself won't remember the last frames emissions. I need help.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript].